# Next perfect number function in Python

Tags: python

What I want to do: If the sum of dividors of a number is equal to the number, I want to print it. If it's not, I want to check if it is true for next numbers and print the smallest number which meets that condition. I've got this:

```
def next_perfect(n):
    sum=0
    for d in range(1, n):
        if n%d==0:
            sum=sum+d
    if sum==n:
        return n
    else:
        sum=0
        n=n+1
        for d in range(1, n):
            if n%d==0:
                sum=sum+d
            if sum==n:
                return n
            else:


print(next_perfect(25))
```

For example for:

```
print(next_perfect(25))
```

It should check 25, then check 26, 27, 28 and print 28.
I don't have an idea how to end this. I want this loop to move back to the first "else" and start checking the conditions again for the next number, always if the number isn't good.

Comment: Don't call your variables `sum` and other builtin python names.

Comment: maybe you should use recursion: `return next_perfect(n+1)`

Comment: @merive_: Bad idea. That rapidly overflows the stack. A plain loop would be a much better option here.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica just set recursion limit: `import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)` I think it should solving a problem

Comment: @merive_: Nope. That just means you get a messy C-level stack overflow instead of a clean Python stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop and `return` when you find the required number:

```
def next_perfect(n):
    while True:
        total=sum(d for d in range(1, n) if n%d==0)
        if total==n:
            return n
        n=n+1

>>> next_perfect(25)
28
```

Or with recursion:

```
def next_perfect(n):
    total=sum(d for d in range(1, n) if n%d==0)
    if total==n:
        return n
    else:
        return next_perfect(n+1)
```

Comment: The recursive approach [rapidly runs out of stack space](https://ideone.com/8LbTTg). A loop is a much better option here.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - Agreed - That's why the loop was my first approach.

Comment: @qwerty22 - Like the first comment here mentions, you should consider using the `while` loop approach which still runs fine for larger numbers (the recursion approach will throw a RecursionError)

Comment: There's a lot of ways to make factorizing more efficient, my answer is simply showing two different ways to answer OP's question.

Comment: correction again it should be `sum(d for d in range(1, n // 2 + 1) if n % d == 0)` for the efficiency

Comment: Perfect numbers are growing rapidly (6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336, 8589869056, ...) so iterating over consecutive integers is not a viable way of finding them too.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your logic in a while loop, increasing n at each iteration  and only exiting the loop when n is a perfect number:

```
def isPerfect(n):
    return 2*n == sum(sum({d,n//d}) for d in range(1,int(n**0.5)+1) if n%d==0)

def nextPerfect(n):
    n += 1
    while not isPerfect(n):
        n += 1
    return n
```

The problem with that solution is the time it will take to reach even the 5th perfect number (you won't want to wait that long).  At that point you might as well hard code the first few perfect numbers in a list:

```
def nextPerfect(n):
    firstPerfects = [6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336, 8589869056, 
                     137438691328, 2305843008139952128, 
                     2658455991569831744654692615953842176,              
                     191561942608236107294793378084303638130997321548169216]
    return next(p for p in firstPerfects if p>n)
```